# Why a function does not change a list correctly in Python

Tags: python

A python script like the following. The list 'a' cannot be updated correctly:

```
   def test(b, a):
        print(a)
        a.append(10)
        a = b
        print(a)
            
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 6]
    test(b, a)
    print(a)
```

The results were printed out like below. The list 'a' was changed as [1, 2, 3, 10] NOT [4, 5, 6]. Why?

Answer (score 1):

you simply created a new local variable `a` that was equal to `b`, that *shadowed* the `a` you passed in

you can do inplace replacement with slice notation

```
a[:] = b
```

would replace the value of a that you passed in

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `return` statement to update `a`. Set `a` equal to the return value of the function.

```
def test(b, a):
        print(a)
        a.append(10)
        a = b
        return a
            
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 6]
    a = test(b, a)
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because by sending the variables `a` and `b` to the function, you created copies of them.

They point to the same data and you can modify it but when you assign a completely different list to the variable in the function, the original variable outside the function stays unchanged.

I would recommend returning the new lists from the function if you want to change the original variables. Like this:

```
def test(b, a):
        print(a)
        a.append(10)
        a = b
        print(a)
        return b, a

        
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
b, a = test(b, a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. Within `test` the variable `a`, `b` are local references to objects `a` and `b` outside of test. Thus `a` and `b` in the context of `test` can be named anything.

Here's the code with some printouts that'll help explain this better:

```
def test(test_b, test_a):
    print('test_a references object in memory {} with values {}'.format(id(test_a), test_a))
    print('append(10)')
    test_a.append(10)
    print('test_a references object in memory {} with values {}'.format(id(test_a), test_a))
    print('assign reference test_a = test_b # new value {}'.format(id(test_b)))
    test_a = test_b
    print('test_a references object in memory {} with values {}'.format(id(test_a), test_a))

outside_a = [1, 2, 3]
outside_b = [4, 5, 6]
test(outside_b, outside_a)
print('outside_a references object in memory {} with values {}'.format(id(outside_a), outside_a))
```

A sample output of this would be like:

```
test_a references object in memory 140058884752448 with values [1, 2, 3]
append(10)
test_a references object in memory 140058884752448 with values [1, 2, 3, 10]
assign reference test_a = test_b # new value 140058887943936
test_a references object in memory 140058887943936 with values [4, 5, 6]
outside_a references object in memory 140058884752448 with values [1, 2, 3, 10]
```